# Which Jenkins file is responsible for Enable cache setting

Tags: jenkins, linux

I want to know how can I modify the below setting from Jenkins server and not UI:

http://XXXXX:YYYYY/configureSecurity/

[image: cache]

Comment: what is the plugin that you have installed? I don't have this option on my jenkins

Comment: I guess LDAP plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/ldap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines in `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` under `securityRealm` and then restart `jenkins` service to enable cache. Remove the below 4 line if you don't want to enable it.

```
<cache>
  <size>500</size>
  <ttl>3600</ttl>
</cache>
```

Please refer the below image

[image: Jenkins config file snippet]